# How to suppress exit status echo?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a batch file that calls a powershell script that calls the same batch file again which calls a different powershell script

- runPowerShell.bat
- scriptWrapper.ps1
- Process.ps1

the flow is: runPowerShell.bat > scriptWrapper.ps1 > runPowerShell.bat > Process.ps1

the batch file contains an echo of the Process.ps1 exit code.

```
    if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 GOTO :error
GOTO :end
:error
echo Exit Code: %ERRORLEVEL%
echo Failed!

EXIT /B %ErrorLevel%
:end
echo Exit Code: %ERRORLEVEL%
echo Success!
```

The thing is, since scriptWrapper runs successfully as well, it also seems to pass back a success even though i have no exit codes in the scriptWrapper.ps1 file. so essentially i end up with two success messages instead of just the one from the Process.ps1 that i want only.

```
Exit Code: 0
Success!
Exit Code: 0
Success!
```

so is there a way to suppress the echo in runPowerShell.bat to ONLY echo from the Process.ps1?

I could create another batch file to handle this scenario, but i would like to see if there is an option that doesnt have to involve another batch file here first.

Comment: Antipattern detected! Just eliminate the circular dependency. That's a really bad design pattern.

Comment: @jwdonahue interesting! i just learned about anti patterns last time, but didnt know this was a case of it lol